# How do I find and replace a word in a text line

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

I tried to remove a symbol, it works, but I can't find a way to remove specific words.

Is there a way someone can teach me how to find and replace a word with spaces?

Someone please show me what I am doing wrong.

```
String TfrmMain::GetCorrectCardName(String Str)
{
    String Name = "";
    String Name_Before = Str;
    String NewName = "";


    //Change the name symbols.
    for(int Name_no = 0; Name_no < Name_Before.Length(); Name_no++)
    {
        NewName = Name_Before[Name_no];
        if(Name_Before.c_str()[Name_no] == '@'||Name_Before.c_str([Name_no] == '\\' 
            || Name_Before.c_str()[Name_no] == '#')
        {
            Name += '/';
        }
        else if(Name_Before.c_str()[Name_no] == '_')
        {
            Name += ' ';
        }
        else if(Name_Before.c_str()[Name_no] == '\'')
        {
            Name += '\'';
        }

        // The error starts here  
        else if (NewName == "*Name")
        {
            Name_Before.Insert("         ",Name_no);
            Name = Name_Before;
            Name_Before++; // Keep the numbers right.
            Name_no++; // Same ^
        }
        // end here 

        else
        {
            Name += Name_Before.c_str()[Name_no];
        }
    }
    return Name;
}
```

Comment: You have a comment that says `// the error starts here`, but you never say anything about an *error* in all of your text. What *error* are you getting exactly?

Comment: You are using 0-based indexes, but `String` uses 1-based indexes instead. `Name_Before.c_str()[Name_no]` expects a 0-based index, but `Name_Before[Name_no]` expects a 1-based index. You are mixing the two approaches in the same loop. Also, `NewName == "*Name"` will NEVER work, since `NewName` only ever holds a single `char` (from `NewName = Name_Before[Name_no];`) And `Name_Before++` doesn't do what you think it does. What are you TRYING to accomplish? What are the rules you are trying to implement? Most of your loop can be replaced with calls to `StringReplace()` instead, for instance.

Comment: consider std::string::find(...)   see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: I've tried so many ways of codes, one of the error is "Find is not ansiString" , then std error and more error. This is the first code i do that doesn't pop out error but when i run this function will pop out "Project @@@.exe raised exception class ERangeError with message"Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue." and will show "ThrowIfOutOfRange(idx);   // Should Range-checking be optional to avoid overhead ??." Im new to C++ languange, so i do not know the logical way for this coding.

Comment: Just a note: Consider upgrading your compiler/IDE. This is from 2002 and you can't learn contemporary C++ with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
String TfrmMain::GetCorrectCardName(String Str)
{
    const TReplaceFlags flags = TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll;

    String Name = StringReplace(Str, "@", "/", flags);
    Name = StringReplace(Name, "\\", "/", flags); 
    Name = StringReplace(Name, "#", "/", flags); 
    Name = StringReplace(Name, "_", " ", flags); 
    Name = StringReplace(Name, "*Name", "         ", flags); 

    return Name; 
}
```

However, `StringReplace()` will loop over the string each time, so if you want to stick with a single manual loop, try something more like this instead:

```
String TfrmMain::GetCorrectCardName(String Str)
{
    String Name;

    for(int Name_no = 1; Name_no <= Str.Length(); ++Name_no)
    {
        switch (Str[Name_no])
        {
            case '@':
            case '\\'
            case '#':
                Name += '/';
                break;

            case '_':
                Name += ' ';
                break;

            case '*':
                if (Str.SubString(Name_no+1, 4) == "Name")
                {
                    Name += "         ";
                    Name_no += 4; // Keep the numbers right.
                    break;
                }
                // fall through to next case

            default:
                Name += Str[Name_no];
                break;
        }
    }

    return Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much remy, your code fix everything i needed. Thank you very much again! ^_^